# What is the definition of $\text{weight or Hodge-Tate weight}$ in the p-adic Hodge theory?

Tags: p-adic-number-theory, hodge-theory, galois-representations

My question is about p-adic Hodge-Tate theory and p-adic Galois representation.

What is the definition of $\text{weight or Hodge-Tate weight}$ in the above theory?

For example, I have the following two definitions of weights in the above context as follows:

**Def 1:**  (https://math.uchicago.edu/~emerton/pdffiles/egh.pdf)

A $\text{weight}$ is an isomorphism class of irreducible representations $V$ of $G(k)$ over $\bar k$, where $k$ is the residue field in the finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$. Since $G(k)$ is finite, there are finitely many weights.

**Def 2:**(http://math.bu.edu/people/bergdall/seminars/hodge-notes/week11.pdf)

A Hodge-Tate weight $i \in \mathbb{Z}$ is defined such that $Gr^{i}D_{HT}(V)=(V \otimes_{\mathbb{Q}_p} \mathbb{C}_p)^{Gal}=\frac{Fil^{i}D_{dR}(V)}{Fil^{i+1}D_{dR}(V)} \neq 0$.

This different definitions makes me into confusion though the later one is a definition of HT weight while the first one is simply weight.

Are the above two weights same or different?

Can someone explain and gives definition of weight in the above sense?

Comment: The second is the definition a Hodge-Tate weight and applies to representations $\rho$ valued in a $p$-adic field. The first is the definition of the inertial weight of a representation valued in a finite field and can be thought of as the analogue of Hodge-Tate weights for mod p reps. Under certain circumstances ($\rho$ must be crystalline, with Hodge-Tate weights small relative to $p$), the Hodge-Tate weights of $\rho$ will equal the inertial weights of $\overline\rho$ in a precise sense. This relation is called Fontaine--Laffaille theory.

Comment: @Mathmo123, thank you for your nice information.

Comment: @Mathmo123, Can you comment please? What does mean by Tate Motive $\mathbb{Z}(1)$ or $\mathbb{Z}_p(1)$ in the p-adic Hodge theory? From wikipedia, I got a link with p-adic cyclotomic character . Here-https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_character

Comment: $\mathbb Z_p(1)$ is $\varprojlim_n\mu_{p^n}$ where $\mu_k$ denotes the $k$-th roots of $1$. As a ring it is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_p$. However, the Galois action is via the cyclotomic character.

Comment: @Mathmo123, is it like the analogue to Tate Module?

Comment: Yes. You can view it as the Tate module of the multiplicative group $\mathbb G_m$.

Comment: @Mathmo123, thank you very much for nice help